# A way to simplify the following code

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have the following code, written in Matlab, to find the combination MW of three units: Units 1, 2 and 3. The logic is the following:

Combine total of Unit 1, store it.

Combine total of Unit 2, store it.

Combine total of Unit 3, store it.

Combine total of Unit 1 and Unit 2, store it.

Combine total of Unit 1 and Unit 2 and Unit 3, store it.

Combine total of Unit 1 and Unit 3, store it.

Combine total of Unit 2 and Unit 3, store it.

Programcaticaly, I am doing it witht he following:

```
%Max MW for each unit
maxMW = [200 60 50];

%Min MW for each unit
minMW = [50 15 15]


%Load Pattern in MW
              %1-2      3-4     5-6     7-8
loadPattern = [250      320     110     75]

%Full load production cost for each unit
productionCost = [15.4  16.0062 16.800  18.060  18.900]  

combination(1) = maxMW(1)
combination(2) = maxMW(2)
combination(3) = maxMW(3)
combination(4) = maxMW(1)+maxMW(2)
combination(5) = maxMW(1)+maxMW(2)+maxMW(3)
combination(6) = maxMW(2)+maxMW(3)
combination(7) = maxMW(1) + maxMW(3)
```

Is there a way to simplify the combination(i) block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order is not important, then this code:

```
M=[1 2 3];
S=0;
for i=1:length(M)
S=S+nchoosek(3,i);
end
combinations=sum((arrayfun(@str2num,num2str(dec2bin(1:S))).*repmat(M,S,1))');
```

gives this:

```
combinations(1)=M(3)
combinations(2)=M(2)
combinations(3)=M(2)+M(3)
combinations(4)=M(1)
combinations(5)=M(1)+M(3)
combinations(6)=M(1)+M(2)
combinations(7)=M(1)+M(2)+M(3)
```

Comment: This is great! A little more complicated than I thought. I need 15 points to rep up, but would if I could. Thanks again!

Comment: It is a bit complicated, Divakar's solution might be nicer for you application actually.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this too -

```
combination(1:3) = maxMW(nchoosek(1:3,3));
combination([4 7 6]) = sum(maxMW(nchoosek(1:3,2)),2)'; %%//'
combination(5) = sum(maxMW(nchoosek(1:3,1)))
```

A more general one could be presented for more number of inputs, if anyone is interested.